# getting data from google plus community and events using google+ API

Tags: api, google-plus, oauth2-playground

Google provide many of its data via api.
Google plus provide data of people,activity,comments.
But its not provide data of new feature like community,events.
How can i access that stuff via google plus api?

I need data of community that i joint and able to post that data vi api.
I also need to show google plus event on my page.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited:** This answer is out of date and no longer works.

Google+ Communities can be treated the same as Profiles and Pages for some things in the Public Data API. You can just replace the profile_id with the community_id and most things will work. The Community probably needs to be public, however. You can only use the `activities.list` and `activities.get` methods to get posts from the community - there is no way to get information about the community itself (the equivalent of `people.get`).

Events are also available using the API and are more or less like comments. There are some differences, of course, and it does not always turn up in search results the same way. You may also want to look into the Google Calendar API and access events through that interface instead.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground .this is playground where you can play with google api ..i tried with this url by replacing user_id with community_id   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}..but its not work...

Comment: I've added some additional information about which methods work for communities and which don't. You're testing using `people.get`, which gets profile info. Since the community doesn't have a profile, it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The APIs do not provide support for getting any type of Google+ Community post even if they are public. In the past this worked, but it was never supported and has since stopped working.

Prisoner's answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature request to access the community activities though it's not currently supported by the public api, here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639